# Where does Netbeans store the information located in Services->Servers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

Where does Netbeans 7.x/8.x store the information located in Services -> Servers ? The server name, installation location, domain folder, catalina home/base, etc.

[image: Servers registered with Netbeans and their configurarion]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find a per-server folder structure under **[NETBEANS_HOME]/nb/config**. Here, the details of each app server/container/Database that has been harnessed by Netbeans are stored here. I presume you're interested in your tomcat deployment. For TC7, you'll find it at

> [NETBEANS_HOME]/nb/config/J2EE/InstalledServers/.nbattrs

Comment: @rodtakular - thanks, I only caught my own error just now that you've pointed it out

Comment: Thank you. To complement your answer, I want to add that you can find information about the servers(generated during the installation process) in the following files:

Regarding Tomcat: 
`[NETBEANS_INSTALL]/nb/config/J2EE/InstalledServers/.nbattrs`

Regarding Glassfish: 
`[NETBEANS_INSTALL]/nb/config/GlassFishEE6/Instances/.nbattrs`

Comment: You can also find the Glassfish servers information in the Netbeans' user directory, here: `[NB_USER_DIRECTORY]/config/GlassFishEE6/Instances/.nbattrs`